# Enhancing geth subscription processing to be able to work with transaction data

Tags: go-ethereum, golang, filters

I'm thinking to have a geth "extension" that would be working with a Geth subscriptions. I would like to filter over pending transactions.

When I'm searching in the code I can see that I can create a `PendingTransactionsSubscription (https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/eth/filters/filter_system.go#L345) but that returns me only hashes.

I would like to be able to work with transaction object within the subscription.
I'm thinking in way I hacked here: https://github.com/ochaloup/go-ethereum/commit/9e4aa4699726ff7a38486d7ba8329cb7e37ff596

Would be possible to pass the `types.Transaction` object instead of `common.Hash` for `PendingTransactionsSubscription` in the oficial Geth release?
Is there some best practice how to bind to the subscription and search through the pending transactions to filter them?

Thank you for ideas